# Clarification on lit-element components and where to browse them

Tags: polymer, polymer-3.x, lit-element

As Polymer 3 migrates to lit-element (hopefully that is an accurate characterization), where is the best place to search for existing/new components that are compatible with lit-element, especially when considering the deprecation of the two-way bindings?

I often search the web components site, and find that when I come across an existing component, even from Polymer, it is an older version for bower, or one that was meant for Polymer 3.  I basically want to search just the lit-element compatible components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the place is still the same: https://www.webcomponents.org/

Only check if the component specifically was made with LitElement or with any of the other Polymer version.

Comment: Thanks for the response. One follow up: If, for example, I wanted to find out the lit-element equivalent for iron-ajax, where would that be?

Comment: In this case you shouldn't search for a component, the current recommendation is just use fetch api